# Changing .xls files to .xlsx files

Tags: python-3.x

I'm basically trying to iterate through a bunch of excel .xls files and change them to .xlsx files and I don't really do not know where to go from here. Feel like I'm making a mess with the code.

I'm getting the following error: TypeError: listdir: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or None, not list

So I messed a little more with he code and it might be going somewhere. I edited the code below.

```
file_path = Path.home().joinpath("Desktop", "test")
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        the_path = (str(file_path) + str("\\"))
        print(the_path)
        os.chdir(the_path)

        xls_files = os.listdir('.')
        print(xls_files)

        for downloadedFile in listdir(xls_files):
            if downloadedFile.endswith('.xls'):
                wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(xls_files)
                pyexcel.save_book_as(downloadedFile, FileFormat = 51)
                downloadedFile.Close()
                downloadedFile.Save()
        excel.Application.Quit()
```

I don't really know if the code I'm writing makes sense at all.
If anyone could help me figure out whether at least I'm in the right track I'd be great.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: "the following error" - what follows is your code, not an error.

Comment: Sorry, actually forgot to copy and paste that part. But I'm getting an error that does not even exist in my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pyexcel` seems to be the right tool for this task.

1. Install three packages

   ```bash
   pip install pyexcel pyexcel-xls pyexcel-xlsx
   ```
2. Run the following script.

   ```py
   from pathlib import Path
   import pyexcel as p


   # Find your home path by print out `Path.home()`
   # Then add additional path that points to the folder that
   # contains all the .xls files.
   # We are essentially using absolute path here, but change
   # it to relative path if necessary.
   folder = Path.home().joinpath('Desktop/test')

   # Iterate all the files inside the folder.
   # Pick the .xls file only and convert it to .xlsx file
   # The converted file will have the same name.
   # E.g. foo.xls will be converted to foo.xlsx
   for file in folder.iterdir():
       if '.xls' in file.suffix:
           book = p.get_book(file_name=str(file))
           book.save_as(file.stem + '.xlsx')
   ```

NOTE:

1. The script has only been tested in macOS, but not Windows. There might be specifics tweaks needed to satisfy the file system in Windows. However,  [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#) shall be able to handle Windows' idiosyncrasies.
2. Tweak the script if special needs arise.